# java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:scala.Predef$.$conforms()Lscala/Predef$$less$colon$less

Tags: scala, maven, apache-spark

I am trying submit scala program to spark,but facing this error:NoSuchMethodError.

[image]

```scala
var spark = SparkSession.builder().enableHiveSupport().getOrCreate()
```

is the error point.

2.11.12 Scala and 2.4.5 Spark are my development environment.

I have googled many times and it seems like a version mismatch problem.

Here is part of my pom.xml and looks like all good.

```
  <dependencies>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.spark/spark-core -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
      <artifactId>spark-core_2.11</artifactId>
      <version>2.4.5</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
      <artifactId>spark-sql_2.11</artifactId>
      <version>2.4.5</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
      <artifactId>spark-hive_2.11</artifactId>
      <version>2.4.5</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.hive/hive-exec -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.hive</groupId>
      <artifactId>hive-exec</artifactId>
      <version>3.1.0</version>
    </dependency>

  </dependencies>

</project>
```

Comment: Are you totally sure your target environment uses **Scala** `2.11` and **Spark** `2.4.5`?

Comment: Did you run a complete maven dependency tree? Could there be any conflicts? Look for unexpected Scala or Spark version as well.

Comment: Oh, it should be var spark = SparkSession.builder().enableHiveSupport().enableHiveSupport().getOrCreate()

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez It's kind of hard to explain... spark version in picture is version 1.5.1 and I have to call `spark-submit xxx.jar` in this version and submit jar to 2.4.5 spark which is depolyed on a background bigdata plateform. I believe the version of scala and spark should match the background one.

Comment: @GaëlJ Yes, no confilcts show there...no warning...